# Error while trying command line output of arguments

Tags: java

What is the error in following code while trying command line arguments ? I am getting an error at line `System.out.println(args[i]);`

```
 public class CommandLA{  
   public static void main(String []args)  
   {  
      int s = 0;  
      for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)  
      System.out.println(args[i]);              
      s = s + Integer.parseInt(args[i]);  
      System.out.println("Sum is : "+s);  
   }  
 }
```

Comment: what are you try to do?

Answer (score 2):

maybe

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
   int s = 0;
   for (String str : args) {
      s = s + Integer.parseInt(str);
   }
   System.out.println("Sum is : "+s);
}
```

or using an indexed for

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
   int s = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      s = s + Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
   }
   System.out.println("Sum is : "+s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)  
  System.out.println(args[i]);
```

followed by

```
s = s + Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
```

But - you are missing the **{** after the loop! Therefore the **scope** in which i exists (is visible) is only the line directly **after** the "for-loop" line!

In other words you need for (..) { all stuff that uses i }!

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the answer of GhostCat:

```
for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)  
System.out.println(args[i]);              
s = s + Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
```

is the same as

```
for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
    System.out.println(args[i]);   
}           
s = s + Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
```

Which means that in the last line, i is not known, resulting in an error.

I wonder why the error was detected at the line before, because until that, the code is technically correct.

That said, I recommend to use brackets in any case. Some people omit them to get shorter code, but that means that if one adds a line later on, he could easily make a mistake. This is personal preference, of course.